# Move cursor to new line character

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode, cursor

When in visual mode you can select the new line character. E.g.:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.⏎
```

In visual mode you can select both the period and the (invisible) carriage return, or even *just* the carriage return (if you delete it you'll join the current and the next lines).

In normal mode, on the other hand, I can't get the cursor on top of that character, which really annoys me. Every now and then I want to select some text *including the new line before it*. So I have to go to visual mode, select what I want and then type `o` and go back a character to select the new line. It would be a lot better if I could have the cursor on the new line to begin with, so I'd just go into visual mode and select what I want.

Any ideas on how to make that happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want the cursor to be able to go one past the end of the line for the purpose of starting visual mode, you want the setting `set virtualedit=onemore` (see `:help 've`).  However, this does not let you remove the new line character in normal mode (in vim you usually use `J` to do this).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `'virtualedit'` for this:

```
:set virtualedit=onemore
```

Note however the warnings in `:help 'virtualedit'`:

> "onemore" is not the same, it will only allow moving the cursor just
>       after the last character of the line.  This makes some commands more
>       consistent.  Previously the cursor was always past the end of the line
>       if the line was empty.  But it is far from Vi compatible.  It may also
>       break some plugins or Vim scripts.  For example because |l| can move
>       the cursor after the last character.  Use with care!

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it was posted 19 seconds before yours, haha, sorry. But thanks!

Comment: @dbmrq Haha. I knew I shouldn't have wasted time pasting in the info from `:help`!